# Parsing CSV file in AWS Athena with commas in quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create an Athena Table from a CSV file which can contain special characters including comma's enclosed in quotation marks for one column "Name".

SAMPLE:

| BookDate | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 8/29/2022 | "ÂŒ," |
| 8/29/2022 | NormalText |

My DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `x`(
  `BookDate` date, 
  `Name` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count'='1', 
  'quoteChar' = '"'
)
LOCATION x
```

OUTPUT:
For the first row, the value

```
"Œ,"
```

is returned (in the console I can see spaces and a comma)

Comment: This is very product specific, so I removed the general <sql> tag (which is for ISO/ANSI SQL.)

Comment: It could be that either the program which displays `"ÂŒ,"` or the program which displays `"Œ,"` is not showing the text correctly even though the correct text is present. Can you show the bytes of the data?